# How do I sort the questions by the number of views?

Tags: support, search, sorting, views

The question is in the title, how do I sort the questions by the number of view?

If not that, I'd settle for any suggestion on how to view the "Most Viewed" questions.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113042/can-we-have-a-sort-by-view-count

Comment: Dupes?: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113846/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343661/282094  - sorting by votes shows higher views usually, but isn't sorted on views:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can at least search for questions based on the number of views:

> [views:500](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A500)

This will search for questions with at least 500 views.

Comment: this doesn't sort them, it just limits you to questions with at least 500 views. Put in "views:500 [c#]" into SO's search bar and sort by votes. You're seeing questions that are tagged C# and have 500 views, but the top of the list is still the one with the most votes. Effective, this accomplished absolutely no sorting. (@random absolutely no offense meant to you, you just posted a good answer that is relevant to the question. I'm just ranting that SO doesn't have this feature. :D )

Comment: I would still like to sort by views, but this is at least a small workaround

Comment: You can even give ranges. (view:10-20) But I would also like to have this feature. I guess the data explorer and a custom query would probably deliver it.