# Sort questions by most viewed

Tags: support, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort the questions by the number of views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-do-i-sort-the-questions-by-the-number-of-views)

I'm just cruising the site looking for interesting stuff. I can look at the questions with the most votes on the "newest, featured, hot, etc." menu, but how can I sort by views?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-do-i-sort-the-questions-by-the-number-of-views

Comment: that only lets you specify a minimum view value, I want to sort them.