# Can we have a sort by view count?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, sorting

It would be great to have Stack Overflow listing sortable by "View Count". This enhances usability, and I guess the Stack Overflow community would also like to know which questions are clicked most, which is an indication on how hot/good its content is, isn't it?

Of course, it should be sorting *regardless* of reply count, votes or other important criteria.

Comment: They used to have this feature.  It was removed because it almost produced the same result s as 'Sort By Votes.'  I doubt that's as true now as it was 2 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for that info, didn't know that. But fact is: Thousands of questions have neither votes, nor comments, replies, flags or anything else. It is supposed to be a simple sort by view count. Maybe someone knows more about why it can't be added?
thanks again

Comment: I dislike this kind of feature.  Take YouTube as an example: often useless videos get a critical mass of views, and then more people view the video to see what everybody is watching.  I think this makes view count *less* useful, actually contravening the value of a sort.

Comment: View count and votes are very different. View count is a better measure of what the search-engine-referred mass want to know, while vote count (on questions) measures how sexy the Stack Overflow user base finds a question. Thus basic usage questions often have huge views but few votes, while esoteric language questions have a greater vote to view ratio.

Answer (score 11):

If you are dying to get this sort you could look at data explorer:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118692/

As it stands there are a ton of sorts we do not support:

- Sort by reply count
- Sort by comment count
- Sort by title length
- Sort by a combination of stuff

We removed the view count sort for a few reasons. Firstly, it was not used that frequently. Secondly, it is incredibly tricky to keep it up to date, too many view counts are constantly changing, a stable sort would mean that we need some pretty radical changes to our tag engine.

> which is an indication on how hot/good its content is, isn't it?

Well no, that is not a particularly good indication. It is an indication of what stuff got traffic, it does not necessarily mean the content is helpful or makes the internet a better place.

As a 10k user you get access to an aggregation of the anonymous feedback at: https://stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback you can use that list to find content that anonymous users deemed helpful, but did not get voting in the last year.

You can also look through the Greatest Hits at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits which is a route that factors views and anonymous voting.