# How can I sort the search results?

Tags: feature-request, search

When searching, you can add several special filters like this:

```
answers:0 [r] closed:no views:2
```

I looked on the [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), but I didn't find how to do to the following:

- look for answer with less than x views, e.g. `views:<10`
- sort the list by date, even though each search result includes a date
- sort the list [by views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-do-i-sort-the-questions-by-the-number-of-views), I found that a similar tool was [removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113042/can-we-have-a-sort-by-view-count)

Does anyone else think these would be useful additions?

Comment: But If I want to sort by the oldest ones? I can't and it also doesn't answer how to search for questions with less than x views. This combined could help to clean old questions without many views to answer if they didn't had already an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [advanced search help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) you can use a range operator. As a question starts with 1 view (the authors) you could use this to search for a question with less than 10 views.

```
views:1..10
```

It doesn't appear to be 100% accurate but it's fairly close.

The search doesn't have a default sort but simply add the tab name you want to sort by to the tab query as per this URL, which sorts by date created.

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=views%3a1..10
```

As the question you've linked to states there is no way to sort by view count. The Data Explorer still exists and so does [the query in that answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/53412). This is not "live" though and is refreshed weekly and the query gets the top 1,000 questions by view count. If you want something different you'd have to create your own query.

Comment: Oh :( I missed this, thanks! Yes, I discovered the Data Explorer recently but that would make it

Comment: Hacking the URL (or clicking the according button after the serach) "works", but I would still find it way more convenient if the search query would have a command as well, say `sort:neweset`. Why not? I have also not found a question for exaclty that (yet), so I might still ask it....