# Search by tag, order by views - how to?

Tags: support, tags, search

When I do a search by tag on SO ([e.g. c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)), is there a way to order the result set by number of views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2169/posts-with-a-given-tag-ordered-by-viewcount) on Data Explorer if you are OK with slightly old information.

Answer (score 5):

I dont think this feature is available. You can search for questions with a specific number of views for a particular tag, such as [c# questions that were viewed at least 5000 times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A5000+[c%23]).