# Listing stackoverflow questions with most views for a given tag (ex: maven)?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort the questions by the number of views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-do-i-sort-the-questions-by-the-number-of-views)

Is it possible to create/obtain a list of stackoverflow questions having the most views for a given tag? I know it is possible to get a list with most votes, but that is not the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a list of questions using a tag, and with a minimum number of views, for example with [[maven] views:10000](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaven%5D%20views:10000&submit=search). It doesn't allow you to sort the answers by the number of views, and it doesn't allow you to set a range, though.

Comment: Good enough, I can live without the sorting. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get that information from the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

That site let's you run arbitrary queries against a monthly-updated data-dump of Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange websites, and view counts are included in that dump.

Example query:

```sql
select top 25 id as [Post Link], viewcount, tags, creationdate
from posts
where tags like '%<python>%'
order by viewcount desc
```

gives the 25 most viewed posts with [python](/questions/tagged/python).