# Sort option: most views

Tags: feature-request, sorting, views

When I'm looking at `questions/tagged/<tag_name>?sort=faq` views of SE sites, I often wish I could have a "most views" sort option.

Especially if I'm completely new to a tag area and want to come up to speed fast, I would prefer to be able to look into the "most viewed questions" of this tag area first, rather than the "most linked", but less viewed ones.

I know this is subjective, but does something generally speak against having a "most views" sort option?

EDIT:

Meanwhile I've learned that you cannot sort, but at least [search a tag area by minimum number of views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-do-i-sort-the-questions-by-the-number-of-views).

That's great and partially solves the problem, but I'm still interested if we can have a "most views" sort option or what does speak against having it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting by the most links *is* what FAQ sorting is for. If you sort by votes, then it's not FAQ sorting anymore. It's sorting by votes. This request frankly makes no sense. If you take something that's already sorted and sort it by another thing, you're either:

1. Sorting it by that single new thing only.
2. Sorting it by the old thing, and then sorting each level of that old thing by the new thing, which in this case wouldn't really change the order at all.

If you just want a flat-out sort option for number of views, you should change your request to that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native speaker, please bear with me. Updating my question.