# How to find out which question is mostly viewed in SO?

Tags: support, questions, sorting, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort option: most views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142090/sort-option-most-views)

In the SO home page, the questions are sorted by newest(time), featured(bounty), faq, votes, active, unanswered.

Is it possible or is there any option to sort the questions by the number of views?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query [Questions with most views](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/90438/questions-with-most-views)