# Why is it not possible to sort question by number of views?

Tags: support, search

As far as I know questions of any SE site can be sorted by the following parameters:

- Newest
- Recent activity
- Most votes
- Most frequent
- Bounty ending soon

[The following related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-do-i-sort-the-questions-by-the-number-of-views) shows that it is possible to sort questions by number of views, like 500, 1.000 etc. but if I want to know which are the top 10 questions  by number of  views on Meta, for instance, would that be possible by a simple request?

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1366496

Comment: SEDE to the rescue!

Answer (score 2):

It *is* possible to do this in the 10k tools (within 30 days):

[image]

But since you don't have 10K, you'll have to use the other sort options, or the `views:<lots> is:question` search query, or [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1366496).

Comment: My interest is not really for this site, but for ELU. If I understand it correctly, that’s a way to see the most viewed questions in the last 30 days?

Comment: @user121863 So use the "Switch to site" part of the query.

Comment: @user121863 good, so you have access to ELU 10k tools. It's not perfect, but surely better than nothing. SEDE is better as it's not limited to 30 days or 10k rep, but you won't see new questions in there.

Comment: Ok, but still that’s not what I am looking for, is it?

Comment: @user121863 true, it's not what you look for, but rather a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Can't know for sure, but my best guess is that the reason is views being a "volatile" detail, which doesn't reflect anything real.

Views count is "nice to have" feature, but that's about it: it has no real value. High views count does not mean a good question. Low views count does not mean a bad question.

All other sort options have some real value.

Comment: Well, I disagree on the lack of value of views. On ELU for instance it is often an indication of a language issues that users appear to have since a lot of views tend to make some questions very searched for , also after the hotlist period.

Comment: @user121863 so you should post a new feature request asking to add such sort option, and mention there what you told here.

Comment: Ok thanks, that a good indication. But before that I wanted to make sure the feature does not exist.

Comment: @user121863 that's true. But wait, don't post new request, [such request already exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142090/sort-option-most-views), I found it now. Sorry for not looking for it before. You can upvote it, edit if you have anything of value to add there, but I'm afraid that's where our options, as regular users, end. Good luck! :)

Comment: I remember trying to search for views (it can be done with regular search) and the results were very inaccurate. In order for the view count to update in the index, you need other activity on the question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184742/323179

Comment: @Laurel wrong answer, lol. My answer doesn't mention the option to search by views count, the other answer does. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating it’s a comment on you saying that the number of views is volatile, though I guess you meant in a different way