# Sorting the question list by number of views

Tags: discussion, questions, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort the questions by the number of views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-do-i-sort-the-questions-by-the-number-of-views)

Currently users can view questions sorted in several ways like

- by date,
- by activity,
- by votes.

But users cannot sort the questions by popularity (that is, by the number of views).

Is it intentionally so? Or does nobody except me need this feature?

Answer (score 1):

**Current ways of finding popular questions**

In the current system there are two ways that you can view questions by popularity:

1. You can use the votes view to view all questions that have been popular.
2. You can view the currently popular questions in the active view.

Regarding the votes view, usually these questions tend to be older and have received many upvotes for their helpfulness. The quality of the question and its answers have driven the question and its popularity.

In the active view, it can be easily apparent which questions are receiving the most traffic and receiving the most upvotes.

**Possible problems with creating a popularity view for questions**

1. Question can receive many views because the title is good or very generic.
2. Question can receive many views because the issue itself is popular.

I have seen many questions that have many views just because they had good wording in the title. However, once you actually read the question, you realize that the OP just made a minor mistake such as a misspelling of a variable; therefore, all the answers are pretty much useless to others.

I have also seen many questions where the question is good, but there are no good answers. Therefore, the current state of the question is of little use, unless you know the answer of course.

**Conclusion**

If we allow the votes and just activity of question to show the popularity it helps to remove some of the questions that are not so good or may not be very helpful. I think the current system handles all situations pretty well, but there may be room for improvement.

Comment: "the votes will drive it up in the votes view" -- of course, there is a correlation, but the difference can be very very strong. you can take a look at your personal questions. They can be sorted by views and by votes, and compare these two lists

Comment: But as I said, some questions can have a good title, but because of inexperience and a minor mistake the question can receive many hits, but it wont be very useful to others. I have some questions from when I was first starting in development that represent this well. However, others may see a need for a popularity view. I do see how some people may like it.

Comment: Yes, Josh, that's right; but there is such information as "number of views" and I think it would be useful (and interesting) to have a ability to get a list of questions sorted in number of views. Why can you have this feature for your own questions (in your profile) but not globally?

Comment: Having your own question being able to be sorted by views is almost a necessity because when looking at the views of your own questions, if there are many views and you have not received many upvotes, it is a good indication that you may need to improve your question. IMHO there is not such an important reason to be able to view all questions in this way. However, I am not saying I am totally against your proposal. There are some obvious benefits. I just wanted mentioned that there could be some negatives.