# How can I get the top x questions for a tag or set of tags based on number of views?

Tags: support, search, views

Is there a way to make a bookmarkable URL of a Stack Overflow search that yields top x questions for a tag or set of tags, based on number of views?  Basically, the frequently asked questions.

Looks like there is no way to specify the sorting order in search.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Frequent' tab lists the questions with the most duplicates, e.g. [the top question for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?tab=Frequent) is [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/4751173)

If you want to sort on the number of views, you'll need a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1196370/top-questions-by-views?TagName=c%23) puts the question above at #11, and indicates [How do I generate a random int number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2706500/4751173) is the top C# question by popularity.

Feel free to fork the query to support a higher number of tags. If you're new to SEDE or SQL in general, please have a look at the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial). SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, but that shouldn't be a real problem for these type of requests.